# How to stop one micro service from consuming the message from Message queue-RabbitMQ

Tags: java, stored-procedures, rabbitmq, message-queue, messaging

Please help me in this scenario

Suppose there are multiple micro service consuming the messages from rabbitmq
But I want to stop for sometime one microservice to consume the message.
1.How will I achieve that?

Real life based scenario of above
Suppose I want to add new messaging vendor(for ex otp sending to mobile) and without letting it know to my previous vendor I want to check whether the new vendor is capable of delivering that load.
in that case I want without changing the code at previous vendor side and without changing the queues name
How we can achieve that?
Please help

Comment: can you explain in detail the architecture flow? From what you described , i believe the microservice is in vendor side and you want to remotely stop that vendor microservice to consume messages? Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

to stop a consumer is enough to use `channel.basicCancel`:

for example:

```
String consumerTag = channel.basicConsume("queue3", consumer);
........ {cosumer messages}
```

then wen you need to stop it:

```
channel.basicCancel(consumerTag)
```

Comment: thanks Gabriele but i dont want to initimate the consumer so what i am come up with is we can use reverse proxy so that my old vendor wont now what is happening and i can test my new vendor